# For large $n$, what is a good upper-bound for $\sqrt{1-x^{1/n}}$ valid for $x \in (0, 1)$?

Tags: real-analysis, approximation, binomial-theorem, upper-lower-bounds

Let $n$ be a large integer.

> **Question.** What is a good upper-bound for $\sqrt{1-x^{1/n}}$ valid for $x \in (0, 1)$ ?

The trivial bound $\sqrt{1-x^{1/n}} \le \sqrt{(1-x)/n}$ which follows from the (fractional) binomial theorem, is very loose for $0 < x \ll 1$.

## Notes

- Philosophically, an upper-bound means to exhibit a relation of the form $f(x) \le g(x)$ where $g(x)$ "looks simpler". For the above question, idealistically, upper-bound with no appearance of $n$ in an exponent of some $x$-expresion...

## Edit

Illustrating bound from user Claude's answer
[image]
Looks pretty tight for large values of $n$, right ?

Comment: How is $\tfrac{\pi+\arcsin(1-2x)}{2\sqrt{n}}$? Also, your trivial bound fails everywhere; it is in fact a *lower* bound.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Didn't know about that. However, the function $arcsin$ is very "non-elementary". What about only working with square-roots and rationals ? :). Don't know how to make this clear in the question without a very cumbersome phrasing :)

Comment: I figured it wasn't what you were looking for, and yes I understand it is difficult to make precise what is a "good" upper bound and what isn't. Claude's answer seems pretty satisfactory, except that it yields a lower bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*No $n$ in the approximation seems difficult (at least to me).*

Composing Taylor series for large values of $n$
$$\log \left(\sqrt{1-x^{\frac{1}{n}}}\right)=-\frac{1}{2} \log \left({n}\right)+\log \left(\sqrt{-\log
   (x)}\right)+\frac{\log (x)}{4
   n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ giving as a quite good approximation
$$\color{blue}{\sqrt{1-x^{\frac{1}{n}}}\sim x^{\frac{1}{4 n}}\sqrt{\frac{-\log (x)}{n}}}  $$

Trying for $n=100$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
x &  x^{\frac{1}{4 n}}\sqrt{\frac{-\log (x)}{n}} & \sqrt{1-x^{\frac{1}{n}}} & \sqrt{\frac{-\log (x)}{n}}\\
 0.05 & 0.1717904 & 0.1717936 & 0.1730818 \\
 0.10 & 0.1508717 & 0.1508734 & 0.1517427 \\
 0.15 & 0.1370843 & 0.1370853 & 0.1377360 \\
 0.20 & 0.1263542 & 0.1263549 & 0.1268636 \\
 0.25 & 0.1173336 & 0.1173341 & 0.1177410 \\
 0.30 & 0.1093959 & 0.1093963 & 0.1097257 \\
 0.35 & 0.1021923 & 0.1021925 & 0.1024608 \\
 0.40 & 0.0955041 & 0.0955042 & 0.0957231 \\
 0.45 & 0.0891811 & 0.0891812 & 0.0893593 \\
 0.50 & 0.0831113 & 0.0831114 & 0.0832555 \\
 0.55 & 0.0772044 & 0.0772045 & 0.0773199 \\
 0.60 & 0.0713808 & 0.0713809 & 0.0714721 \\
 0.65 & 0.0655634 & 0.0655634 & 0.0656341 \\
 0.70 & 0.0596690 & 0.0596691 & 0.0597223 \\
 0.75 & 0.0535974 & 0.0535974 & 0.0536360 \\
 0.80 & 0.0472117 & 0.0472117 & 0.0472381 \\
 0.85 & 0.0402973 & 0.0402973 & 0.0403136 \\
 0.90 & 0.0324507 & 0.0324507 & 0.0324593 \\
 0.95 & 0.0226451 & 0.0226451 & 0.0226480
\end{array}
\right)$$

So, it seems that we have a lower and an upper bound.

$$\color{blue}{  x^{\frac{1}{4 n}}\sqrt{\frac{-\log (x)}{n}} < \sqrt{1-x^{\frac{1}{n}}} <\sqrt{\frac{-\log (x)}{n}}  }$$

**Edit**

What Barry Cipra proposed seems to be significantly better.

Comment: Thanks Claude. Actually, the approximation looks very tight (i.e error is very very small). But then I think I know why. You see, the thing $\sqrt{1-x^{1/n}}$ resulting from an attempt of mine to bound the quantity $y = \sqrt{1-e^{-\frac{\sqrt{\log(1/x)} + \log(1/x)}{2n}}}$. I simply used the (crude) fact that $\log(1/x) + \sqrt{\log(1/x)} \le 2\log(1/x)$ to get $y  \le \sqrt{1- x^{1/n}}$. Claudes's bound seems to have partially uncovered the original problem is way trying to solve in the first place.

Comment: See edited question. Added a small figure illustrating Claude's bound.

Comment: Actually, for $x \in (0, 1)$ and large $n$, the factor $x^{4/n}$ is very close to $1$, and so can be removed, thus given the simplified bound $\sqrt{1-x^{1/n}} \le \sqrt{\log(1/x)/n}$, which is still very tight. See figures in my quesiton.

Comment: @dohmatob. If you look in the table, I have a lower bound (blue formula) and the upper bound is the same removin the $x^{4/n}$ factor. By the way, could you change the plots (make them for $n=10,20,30,100$). I never planned small values of  $n$. It will make the edit much better. Cheers.

Comment: Ok, didn't look at your table. Indeed, you also had that bound. As for the plots, well it's meant to be instructive, nothing more. It shows that the bounds are good for large values of $n$, which is what I'm interested in, but off for small values of $n$, which I'm not interesting in.

Comment: For the record, the second bound in Claude's answer results directly from $y / (y + 1) < 1 - e^{-y} < y$, valid for $y > -1$.

Comment: @dohmatob: Is a logarithm more acceptable than a root ??

Comment: Yes, it fits the bill perfectly. The $n$ doesn't appear as an exponent of an $x$-expression (as explained in the question...). Also the bound is tight. Why are you surprised ?

Comment: Claude, please see my answer for a small improvement on your upper bound formula.

Answer (score 1):

For some purposes, the bound $\sqrt{1-x^{1/n}}\le1$ is good enough. Better, of course, is

$$\sqrt{1-x^{1/n}}\le\sqrt{1-x}$$

But as the OP points out (in comments to the original version of this answer), neither of these bounds is very good when $n$ is large, except at $x=0$ (in both cases) and near $x=1$ (in the latter case).

A better bound -- and an improvement on Claude Leibovici's $\sqrt{|\log x|\over n}$ result -- can be obtained from the inequality

$$1-e^{-z}\le{2z\over2+z}\quad\text{for }z\ge0$$

with $z=-(\log x)/n$.  We obtain

$$\sqrt{1-x^{1/n}}\le\sqrt{2|\log x|\over2n+|\log x|}$$

The main advantage of this bound occurs for $x\approx0$: We have ${2|\log x|\over2n+|\log x|}\le2$ for all $x\gt0$, whereas for any fixed $n$, we have ${|\log x|\over n}\to\infty$ as $x\to0^+$.

Comment: I'll delete this shortly. I saw the "no appearance of $n$" in the question, but didn't register the "in an exponent" part of the sentence.

Comment: This is a very good upper bound ! Thanks.

Comment: Cool. Thanks. Note that since $x \in (0, 1)$, we have $|\log(x)| = -\log(x) = \log(1/x)$, which should simplify what you've written (by removing the absolute-value signs).

Comment: @dohmatob, until I switched from $2n-\log x$ to $2n+|\log x|$ I kept confusing myself, thinking that the subtraction was making the denominator *smaller*, not bigger. The absolute value signs, for me, obviate the need to think.

Comment: Sure. If you're disturbed by the minus sign, then formula $|\log(x)| = \log(1/x)$, removes both the minus sign and the abs-sign. No ? :). Also, $\log(1/x)$ is instructive compared to $|\log(x)|$. Indeed, $\log(1/x)$ says "hey, this is a big quantity" (since $x$ is small and so $1/x$ is big).

Answer (score 1):

*I prefer to add another answer to cover what seems to be the real problem.*

In comments, @dohmatob explained that the real problem was for
$$\sqrt{1-e^{-\frac{\log \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+\sqrt{\log
   \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}}{2 n}}}$$ which I shall consider in the form
$$\sqrt{1-e^{-\frac{k}{ n}}} \qquad \text{with}\qquad k=\frac 12 \left(\log \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+\sqrt{\log
   \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)} \right)$$

For sure, we could adapt Barry Cipra' solution for the initial problem.

Using the simplest Padé approximant, we can write
$$f_n=\sqrt{1-e^{-\frac{k}{ n}}}\sim \frac{4 \sqrt{k n}}{k+4 n}=g_n$$ and all calculations *seem* to confirm that $f_n < g_n$.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
x & f_{10} & g_{10} & f_{20} & g_{20} & f_{30} & g_{30} \\
 0.01 & 0.53524626 & 0.53578216 & 0.39408621 & 0.39419365 & 0.32622013 &
   0.32626080 \\
 0.02 & 0.50506690 & 0.50546031 & 0.37002676 & 0.37010438 & 0.30577897 &
   0.30580819 \\
 0.03 & 0.48561695 & 0.48593657 & 0.35472284 & 0.35478530 & 0.29283270 &
   0.29285614 \\
 0.04 & 0.47085583 & 0.47112748 & 0.34320523 & 0.34325796 & 0.28311638 &
   0.28313612 \\
 0.05 & 0.45877877 & 0.45901579 & 0.33384049 & 0.33388625 & 0.27523249 &
   0.27524959 \\
 0.10 & 0.41697472 & 0.41711869 & 0.30179781 & 0.30182514 & 0.24835956 &
   0.24836972 \\
 0.15 & 0.38861766 & 0.38871761 & 0.28035851 & 0.28037729 & 0.23046082 &
   0.23046778 \\
 0.20 & 0.36609954 & 0.36617301 & 0.26348492 & 0.26349862 & 0.21641539 &
   0.21642045 \\
 0.25 & 0.34685670 & 0.34691237 & 0.24916233 & 0.24917265 & 0.20451995 &
   0.20452376 \\
 0.30 & 0.32967964 & 0.32972255 & 0.23644690 & 0.23645482 & 0.19397844 &
   0.19398135 \\
 0.35 & 0.31388484 & 0.31391824 & 0.22480867 & 0.22481481 & 0.18434477 &
   0.18434702 \\
 0.40 & 0.29903566 & 0.29906174 & 0.21391134 & 0.21391612 & 0.17533648 &
   0.17533823 \\
 0.45 & 0.28482423 & 0.28484459 & 0.20351963 & 0.20352335 & 0.16675646 &
   0.16675782 \\
 0.50 & 0.27101288 & 0.27102869 & 0.19345356 & 0.19345643 & 0.15845436 &
   0.15845542 \\
 0.55 & 0.25740031 & 0.25741248 & 0.18356236 & 0.18356457 & 0.15030471 &
   0.15030552 \\
 0.60 & 0.24379833 & 0.24380758 & 0.17370679 & 0.17370847 & 0.14219205 &
   0.14219266 \\
 0.65 & 0.23001149 & 0.23001837 & 0.16374396 & 0.16374521 & 0.13399839 &
   0.13399884 \\
 0.70 & 0.21581323 & 0.21581822 & 0.15351006 & 0.15351096 & 0.12558895 &
   0.12558927 \\
 0.75 & 0.20091002 & 0.20091350 & 0.14279461 & 0.14279523 & 0.11679107 &
   0.11679129 \\
 0.80 & 0.18487420 & 0.18487649 & 0.13129283 & 0.13129324 & 0.10735521 &
   0.10735536 \\
 0.85 & 0.16699267 & 0.16699404 & 0.11849837 & 0.11849861 & 0.09686737 &
   0.09686746 \\
 0.90 & 0.14583635 & 0.14583704 & 0.10339861 & 0.10339873 & 0.08450015 &
   0.08450020 \\
 0.95 & 0.11744221 & 0.11744245 & 0.08318823 & 0.08318827 & 0.06796219 &
   0.06796220 \\
 0.96 & 0.10986307 & 0.10986324 & 0.07780275 & 0.07780278 & 0.06355780 &
   0.06355781 \\
 0.97 & 0.10097970 & 0.10097981 & 0.07149485 & 0.07149487 & 0.05840022 &
   0.05840022 \\
 0.98 & 0.08991159 & 0.08991165 & 0.06364157 & 0.06364158 & 0.05198069 &
   0.05198069 \\
 0.99 & 0.07416134 & 0.07416137 & 0.05247613 & 0.05247613 & 0.04285642 &
   0.04285642 
\end{array}
\right)$$

In terms of *approximation*, we can still improve. Below are given some expressions
$$\sqrt{\frac{k}{n}}\, \frac{24 n-k}{24 n+5k}$$
$$\sqrt{\frac{k}{n}}\, \frac{480 n^2-48 k n+7k^2}{480 n^2+72kn}$$

Comment: Interesting approach. Upvoted.